# instance Show - can't get it to compile

Tags: haskell

I've got this problem for college where I've got this:

```
data Expression a = Constant a 
                | Simetric (Expression a) 
                | Addition (Expression a) (Expression a) 
                | Subtraction (Expression a) (Expression a) 
                | Multiplication (Expression a) (Expression a)
```

and I've to write Expression a as an instance of *Show*.

Here's my code:

```
instance Show Expression where
               show (Constant x) = (show x)
               show (Simetric x) = "-" ++ (show x)
               show (Addition x y) = (show x) ++ " + " ++ (show y)
               show (Subtraction x y) = (show x) ++ " - " ++ (show y)
               show (Multiplication x y) = (show x) ++ " * " ++ (show y)
```

And I get this error message on ghci when I try to compile:

```
    Expecting one more argument to ‘Expression’
The first argument of ‘Show’ should have kind ‘*’,
  but ‘Expression’ has kind ‘* -> *’
In the instance declaration for ‘Show Expression’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Can someone explain me what's wrong in my code? I've got a final exam on Monday. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read compiler's messages, as it tries very hard to be helpful.

```
Expecting one more argument to ‘Expression’
```

Let's add some argument.

```
instance Show (Expression a) where
```

GHC complains again:

```
No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of ‘show’
Possible fix:
  add (Show a) to the context of the instance declaration
```

Ok, let's add `Show a` to the context:

```
instance Show a => Show (Expression a) where
```

Now it compiles fine. And by the way, you don't need braces around `show`:

```
instance Show a => Show (Expression a) where
    show (Constant x) = show x
    show (Simetric x) = "-" ++ show x
    show (Addition x y) = show x ++ " + " ++ show y
    show (Subtraction x y) = show x ++ " - " ++ show y
    show (Multiplication x y) = show x ++ " * " ++ show y
```

Comment: You need the braces if there's more than one class constraint, just for reference.

Comment: Thanks very much! That solved my problem perfectly!
But I don't understand why do I have to add Show a to the context in the 4th step you made.

Comment: To use `show x` in instance definition you need `x` to be showable. You can't show something that is not instance of `Show`. E.g. `Constant id` where `id` is a function.